# What kind of attack would a 128 bit SHA-2 be vulnerable to and why?

Tags: encryption, hash, keys, sha-2

With SHA-2 for hashing, using only the first 128 bits to create a 128 bit hash, what kind of attack would this be vulnerable to and why?

Since 128 bit encryption keys are secure, shouldn't a 128 bit hash also be secure?

Would this be insecure against a brute force attack?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Think of the birthday problem, for which situation would the birthday problem be an issue? How many bits of security would remain if the birthday problem applies?

Comment: There was a question about [What are the consequences of removing a single byte from a sha256 hash?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64314/18298). The same problem with different values. plug and play.

Comment: What is better, brute force attack or  the birthday attack?

Comment: Sometime, birthday attack is considered brute force. But if the problem explicitly asks about brute force attack versus birthday attack, then likely it considers brute force (preimage) attack as: try messages until hitting a given target hash. What is the likelihood of success of that strategy? Is it high enough that it is not doomed in practice? How does it compare to a birthday attack (see my [Birthday problem for cryptographic hashing, 101](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555)).

Comment: @fgrieu after talking with some people we decided bday attack (kind of brute force) is the correct, but which kind of bday attack specifically?

Comment: The classic reference for implementation of birthday attacks using a practical amount of memory is Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener, [_Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications_](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816).

Comment: @fgrieu can you point me to the specific section? can't find bday attack anywhere in there

Comment: Birthday attack = collision search. See section 4.1 with "small" = 1.