# Is it possible to limit possible inputs of a SHA256 output

Tags: sha-256

my question is as in the title.
For example, there are 2^256 different values ​​that a SHA256 code can take.
But is it possible to shorten this number somehow?

Comment: Please be detailed about what are you asking and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean like this one? [What are the consequences of removing a single byte from a sha256 hash?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64314/18298)